# Mongodate convert

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

After executing the query

```
$orders = Orders::connection()->connection->command(array(
  'aggregate' => 'orders',
  'pipeline' => array( 
    array( 
      '$group' => array( 
        '_id' => array('cust_id'=>'$cust_id','ord_date'=>'$ord_date'),
      'total' => array( '$sum' => '$price') ,
        ),
      ),
    )
));
```

I get the output array of $orders as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [cust_id] => xyz123
                    [ord_date] => MongoDate Object
                        (
                            [sec] => 1351875851
                            [usec] => 102000
                        )

                )

            [total] => 75
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [cust_id] => abc123
                    [ord_date] => MongoDate Object
                        (
                            [sec] => 1351875851
                            [usec] => 102000
                        )

                )

            [total] => 125
        )

)
```

I have tried the following with MongoDate object to print it correctly

```
foreach($orders['result'] as $o){
    $date = $o['ord_date'];
    echo date('Y-M-d',$date->sec);
}
```

Also tried

```
foreach($orders['result'] as $o){
    $date = new MongoDate ($o['ord_date']);
    echo date('Y-M-d',$date->sec);
}
```

Can some one show me the correct method to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `_id` level of your object.  Try this instead:

```
foreach($orders['result'] as $o){
    $date = $o['_id']['ord_date'];
    echo date('Y-M-d',$date->sec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I really missed the _id